# Install dependency’s extras if package’s specific extras is requested

Tags: python, python-poetry

My project has Celery as a dependency. It’s a hard dependencies, ie. my project can’t live without it. However, it can use Redis as its backend, which my app doesn’t need specifically.

I want my package to be set up so if a user installs dependencies with `poetry install -E redis`, it would install the `redis` block of Celery (as if it were specified in `pyproject.toml` as `celery = { version="^4.4.0", extras=["redis"] }`).

However, if a user uses a plain `poetry install` (without `-E redis`), i don’t want Celery’s Redis dependencies (as if it were only specified as `celery = "^4.4.0"`) to be installed.

Is there a way to put this into Poetry config? Or should I track the optional requirements of `celery[redis]` and manually add them to my `pyproject.toml` file?

I already checked the [Poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#expanded-dependency-specification-syntax) on this matter, but it doesn’t offer a way to specify the same dependency (`celery` in my case) with different options.

Comment: heyo, I tried to find a solution but couldn't, seems like tracking `celery[redis]` by hand is the only way right now. For what it's worth, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2868) to bring it some attention, the whole "optional dependency"->"extras" part was solved in a real weird way.

Comment: What about letting your users do it themselves? If they want the flavor `celery[redis]` they should put that in their dependencies (which will get resolved for you) and configure the redis anyway. It seems your project has nothing to do with redis and propagating this option through your scope isn't so neat.

Answer (score 0):

This should work by defining `redis` as an optional [extra](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras), e.g.:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypackage"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["finswimmer <finswimmer@example.org>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
celery = "^4.4.7"
redis = { version = "^3.5.3", optional = true }

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[tool.poetry.extras]
redis = ["redis"]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=1.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

Comment: Although you are technically right in this scenario, but if Celery introduces another dependency for Redis support, i will have to track it and add to my optional dependency list. What i want is to install `celery[redis]` if i install with `poetry install -E redis` so i donʼt have to care about Celeryʼs own deus list.